# java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Flow found in modules annotations-16.0.1.jar and annotations-java5-15.0.jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Text of the output:

```
 Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Flow found in modules annotations-16.0.1.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1) and annotations-java5-15.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
  Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Identifier found in modules annotations-16.0.1.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1) and annotations-java5-15.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
  Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants found in modules annotations-16.0.1.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1) and annotations-java5-15.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
  Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$AdjustableOrientation found in modules annotations-16.0.1.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1) and annotations-java5-15.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
  Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$BoxLayoutAxis found in modules annotations-16.0.1.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1) and annotations-java5-15.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
  Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$CalendarMonth found in modules annotations-16.0.1.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1) and annotations-java5-15.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
  Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$CursorType found in modules annotations-16.0.1.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1) and annotations-java5-15.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
  Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$FlowLayoutAlignment found in modules annotations-16.0.1.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1) and annotations-java5-15.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
  Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$FontStyle found in modules annotations-16.0.1.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1) and annotations-java5-15.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
  Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$HorizontalAlignment found in modules annotations-16.0.1.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1) and annotations-java5-15.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
  Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$InputEventMask found in modules annotations-16.0.1.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1) and annotations-java5-15.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
  Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$ListSelectionMode found in modules annotations-16.0.1.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1) and annotations-java5-15.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
  Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$PatternFlags found in modules annotations-16.0.1.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1) and annotations-java5-15.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
  Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TabLayoutPolicy found in modules annotations-16.0.1.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1) and annotations-java5-15.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
  Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TabPlacement found in modules annotations-16.0.1.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1) and annotations-java5-15.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

It's the Conflict between two jars. You can either figure out which one you are not using from Modules_annotation 16.XXX and annotations-java5-XXXX jar files.

I found out two ways to solve this.

1. Excluding the JetBrains annotations module is a workaround; why is it in your project in the first place? Most likely, it got automatically added to your classpath by Android Studio when what you really wanted was Android's own annotations.

So, a better solution is to look for an org.jetbrains:annotations dependency in your build.gradle file[s], like this:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
```

...and remove it.

If 1 is not working

2. Please add the following line in your Module level build.gradle.

> ```
> configurations {
>             cleanedAnnotations
>              compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains' , module:'annotations'
>          }
> ```

Comment: This worked for me too after the annotations line was added to my gradle file after doing a conversion to kotlin as described here:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/java-to-kotlin/?hl=th#2

Comment: doesn't work at all. Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Build #AI-221.6008.13.2211.9477386, built on January 11, 2023, Runtime version: 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

Comment: I was working on a project i had done years ago and got this issue the solution worked for me.

Answer (score 41):

I fixed the issue on mine by changing the

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.0-beta01'
```

to

```
annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.0-beta01'
```

Comment: and don't forget about kapt

Answer (score 28):

[Harsh Mishra's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8385680) answer is correct, however latest versions of Android Studio no longer declare `org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0` or `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$version_kotlin` in your gradle dependencies and the use of **compile** was also replaced by **implementation**, with this your build.gradle should look like this:

```
    plugins {
        ...
    }

    android {
        ...
    }

    configurations {
        cleanedAnnotations
        implementation.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains' , module:'annotations'
    }

    dependencies {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I was first having 
*compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains' , module:'annotations'* but after upgrading my Gradle it was no more working so, I replaced the COMPILE with IMPLEMENTATION as mentioned above and now it is working.

Comment: This worked for me as well, this should be the current solution as of today

Comment: This worked with Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 4

Answer (score 6):

It's a conflict between single artifact in two different lib/jar files. basically we need to remove the unused lib or remove the artifact from any one lib.

Starting from [Kotlin 1.4](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew14.html#dependency-on-the-standard-library-added-by-default) you no longer need the below dependency

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$version_kotlin"
```

So removing this dependency will also solve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

None of the suggestions worked for me from out of the box, though the second part of the accepted answer is correct - it depends on the specifics of the build.gradle implementation. In order to be safe with almost every implementation do this:

```
configurations {
    cleanedAnnotations
    compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains' , module:'annotations'
    api.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains' , module:'annotations'
    implementation.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains' , module:'annotations'
}
```

Thus making sure all the major dependency inclusion ways are covered.

Comment: how to use this ?

Comment: @DimasLanjaka, well, it should be used in the configurations section of your build.gradle file.

Comment: like this `cleanedAnnotations libs.androidx.room` ? or ?

Answer (score 2):

I change it  implementation `("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")` with this
`annotationProcessor ("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.0-beta01")`

Answer (score 2):

i faced this problem too. After spending much time searching for result, I have replaced  implementation 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2' with annotationProcessor  'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2' and the problem got solved

Answer (score 1):

For a  `org.jetbrains:annotations-java5` dependency in a library, would need to add `annotations-java5` as module instead of `annotations`.

```
configurations {
        cleanedAnnotations
        implementation.exclude group: "org.jetbrains", module: "annotations-java5"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed
`implementation("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.0")`
to
`kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.0")`

I hope it will help, if somebody get the same situation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I put by error the same library twice.

```
implementation(Libs.AndroidX.room)
implementation(Libs.AndroidX.room)
```

I remove one, and everything is working fine now.