# Duplicate class found in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, debugging, duplicates, fixed

It is my problem with my app.

[image]
Execution failed for task ':app: check Debug Duplicate Classes".

```
A failure occurred while executing "com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable"
   > Duplicate class  found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$AdjustableOrientation found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class "org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$BoxLayoutAxis" found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class "org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$CalendarMonth" found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class "org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$CursorType" found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class "org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$FlowLayoutAlignment" found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class "org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$FontStyle" found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$HorizontalAlignment found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$InputEventMask found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$ListSelectionMode found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$PatternFlags found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TabLayoutPolicy found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TabPlacement found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TitledBorderJustification found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TitledBorderTitlePosition found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TreeSelectionMode found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.MagicConstant found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Pattern found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.PrintFormat found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.PrintFormatPattern found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.RegExp found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Subst found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.Nls found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.NonNls found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.PropertyKey found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
     Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.TestOnly found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:133)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:333)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:320)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:313)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:299)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:143)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:227)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:218)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:140)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkItemExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:339)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.lambda$waitForItemsAndGatherFailures$2(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:341)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:326)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:127)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForAll(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForCompletion(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:227)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:171)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:60)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:180)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:110)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:114)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNoEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:249)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:86)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:287)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:144)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:133)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:333)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:320)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:313)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:299)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:143)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:227)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:218)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:140)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Identifier found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$AdjustableOrientation found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$BoxLayoutAxis found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$CalendarMonth found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$CursorType found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$FlowLayoutAlignment found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$FontStyle found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$HorizontalAlignment found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TabPlacement found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TitledBorderJustification found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TitledBorderTitlePosition found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)
-java5:15.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicateClassesDelegate.run(CheckDuplicateClassesDelegate.kt:65)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable.execute(CheckDuplicateClassesDelegate.kt:91)
    at org. workers. internal. Default Worker Server. execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:270)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:119)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
     2 more
```

I try some guided but it isn't work
I added configurations
[image]

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58903820/java-lang-runtimeexception-duplicate-class-org-intellij-lang-annotations-flow-f

Comment: You don't need to include the entire log output. This isn't helpful. a few relevant lines is enough.

Answer (score 2):

I usually get this error when I **wrongfully** use `implementation` instead of `kapt` or `annotationProcessor`.

Try checking your module's build.gradle if it shows any warning like this

[image]

If I try to build my project with that configuration, I get a duplicate class error, so if you see this warning, you should use `kapt` instead.

```
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0-beta01'
```

I'm not sure though if it would fix yours.